# Replaced logo with same name with different image ,unable to run application

Tags: android, xml

I replaced image in drawable folder with same name and different image.

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication, PID: 11892
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication/com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication:drawable/logo2" (7f08011c) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f08011c a=-1 r=0x7f08011c}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2605)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2543)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:162)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11892 SIG: 9
    Application terminated.
```

I tried replacing previous image, no use 
Didn't find any reference for this issue.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_margin="16dp"
     android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
     app:errorEnabled="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
     android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/email"
     android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent">
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewForgotPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is main activity page of application where logo to be shown,logo in under drawable folder.
I am not able to understand this line in LOG

" Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class ImageView"

[image: DRWABLE FOLDER]

Comment: Rename the image drawable to logo_two

Comment: added drawable folder screenshot, please check

Comment: move or copy your image (logo2) from drawable-v24 to drawable folder !

Comment: I am working in android mode, I thought if I place image in drawable folder , it will take the image.

Comment: I changed to project mode and copied the images to drawable, now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. my problem has occurred because I just had used image (icons) in the "drawable-v24" folder. I solved it by copying that into "drawable" folder

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication:drawable/logo2`"

this is error .... you are trying set image which is not there in res/drawable folder